# SQL Server scrtipting loses original format of a compiled script

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Has anyone experienced this and come up with a solution?

SQL Server 2016 Enterprise on Windows Server 2012R2

Using the scripting tool from SSMS and it seems something has changed recently. The output from the SQL Server scripting engine does not resemble the way I have scripted stored procedures, for example, any longer; not even close.

I have used these tools for a long time and while there are some nuances this has an effect on my coding conventions and source code control.
Output from SQL server scripting - parameters are put on one line, indenting is lost, joins are split on multiple lines, case is changed. :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAdverseReaction]
@ID INT
AS
SELECT arc.CategoryName,
       ar.*
FROM   AdverseReaction AS ar
       INNER JOIN
       AdverseReactionCategory AS arc
       ON arc.ID = ar.CategoryID
WHERE  ar.ID = @ID;

-- input --
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAdverseReaction
(
    @ID int
)
AS
    SELECT arc.CategoryName, ar.* 
        FROM AdverseReaction ar
            INNER JOIN AdverseReactionCategory arc ON arc.ID = ar.CategoryID
        WHERE ar.ID = @ID

GO
```

See answer below and read more here: [Parameterization for Always Encrypted](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/12/13/parameterization-for-always-encrypted-using-ssms-to-insert-into-update-and-filter-by-encrypted-columns/)

Comment: Could you try to elaborate here please? I don't understand what you're trying to ask. Try to give examples of the behaviour you're seeing, when it's happening, and explain why it isn't desired.

Comment: Neither SSMS or SQL Server is doing that. SQL Server stores the DDL **exactly** as you wrote it. If it's changing after you've deployed it, then that is being caused by a different tool, or someone else. Take a look at this [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=31e961fb1f579af0e75bacd63fef7794), for example, which shows exactly how the DDL is stored.

Comment: No it is definitely changed when compiled; this is not happening on SQL Server Standard 2016

Comment: I've used SQL Server 2008-SQL Server 2019 CTP. I have never seen this behaviour whatever tool I use to deploy to SQL Server; `sqlcmd`, SSMS, Azure Data Studio, Agent, Dynamic SQL, you name it. Unles you can provide a way for us to replicate this, I very much will still say that this an environment issue. *Maybe* someone's got a DDL trigger on the database that changes the formatted (and would be an insane trigger)... Don't know, but SSMS, nor SQL Server, will change the format a of query parsed.

Comment: Not happening on SQL Server developer either so that's a clue. Thanks for your help. I have to leave this alone until later. I will look into that DDL trigger thing.

Comment: Please see my answer: it's related to the query options and came about because we are using the new "always encrypted" scenario and thus checked this box ... read more at link provided

Comment: Please see that "First thing to note is that SSMS has rewritten the query  ..." and apparently does other things too based on my experience. You can reproduce this problem by checking that box in the "Query Options" advanced tab

Answer (score 1):

I found in SSMS "Query Options" when the checkbox "Enable Parameterization for Always Encrypted" the script is reformatted as described, before it is executed. I unchecked that and things returned to normal. I am guessing this is specific to this version of SSMS. i.e. >= 17